# How to find <script> by id

Tags: javascript, html

I have a `<script>` where it adds to the `<head>` another script.
This new script is supposed to find the original `<script>` that inserted it.
can I put `<script id="blablabla">` and let the new `<script>` find it?

```
<div id="placeholder-1"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
            <//![CDATA[
            (function() {
             var s = document.createElement("script");
             s.type = "text/javascript";
             s.async = true;
             s.src = "blablabla.com/blabla.js";
             (document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] ||
              document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]).appendChild(s);
             })();//]]></script>
```

Now, the blabla.js needs to find the div placeholder.
I am trying to save that div placeholder, by giving it's id already to the script.

is that a browser compatible?

thanks

Comment: if you could show some code of the script manipulation that you are doing it would be helpful.

Comment: In fact I would like to ask why you want the script's id but not the placeholder? WHat's the point of referencing to the script tag?

Comment: The script is a code I want people to embed. I dont want them to put too much code. I'm trying to do it as short as possible

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In HTML 5, just place an `id` attribute on the `script` tag.

```
     <script id="myscript">
         // Your script here
     </script>
```

In HTML 4, the id tag isn't actually defined as being valid on a script tag.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html#edef-SCRIPT Official W3C Specification

Only src, type, langugage, defer and charset are officially allowed.

A valid work around would be this...

```
<div id="scriptcontainer">
     <script type="text/javascript">
         // Your script here
     </script>
</div>
```

You can now traverse to the script using the id of the div element in your "blabla.js"

```
var myScript = document.getElementById("scriptcontainer").getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
```

So essentially, by nesting the script inside of an element with an id, we can get to the script from another script and also have valid markup.

Additional note: in the HTML 4 spec, id was genuinely not allowed on the script tag:

> id    All elements but BASE, HEAD, HTML, META, SCRIPT, STYLE, TITLE   ID
>     #IMPLIED            document-wide unique id

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do it. `id` is one of the global attributes and those may be specified on all HTML elements (even those not defined in html specification). The tag [script](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#script) itself has allowed

```
Content attributes:
Global attributes
src
async
defer
type
charset
```

**EDIT**

Note, that this information is taken from the HTML5 spec. I am not sure of the previous versions, which might still be used in tutorials.

As such, it should be already browser compatible with all major browsers (ie those claiming to support HTML5).

Comment: by reading http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_standardattributes.asp, I found that script and some other tags did not support `id`, `class`, `style`, etc. BUT I do tried adding `id` to a script tag and I can locate it by using $("#script_id") in jQuery.

Comment: The question is - if its legal and browsers compatiable (safari & all)

Comment: Note that technically this is only true of HTML5. Previous HTML specs explicitly did not allow the `id` attribute on `script` tags. I suspect most browsers would render it fine in an HTML 4 document — it would just be invalid — though it would kill rendering for XHTML 1.1 documents.

Answer (score 1):

`showtime = setInterval("Time()", 1000)` at the end of the js script for instance, last line.

With this you can put the script in the head tag area, and call the script by its id, in this case `id=time`.
I use it on my timer on the webpage, and by adding some zeros to the 1000, say add 15 zeros and of course change the id time to whatever you like, you can obviously fool the browser long enough to get away with it,...

Whats the odds that some stay on the webpage for 10000000000000000000000 milliseconds, when the tick comes though you will get an error, so don't set it to short.

Btw the question above was why I came to this page, since I was looking to find a better way then to fool the browser, but having read all answers, I think I will keep on fooling it!

For good measure I used something similar to this in the body:
"`<center<FONT SIZE="2" COLOR="#003300"><b><div id=time></div></b></FONTcenter>`"

A week has 604800000 milliseconds, I think you close your page first.

http://www.temnolooi.nl/2014a/agenda/agenda.html

note: Do take note though of the fact that putting scripts in the head tags will load the file, so dont overuse it, or you may get a stack overflow. Scripts in the body are only executed when the HTML has use for it, or the user calls it forth.